# Travel companion arriving at different terminal at CDG

Tags: cdg

I arrive at terminal 2 two hours before my traveling companion arrives in terminal 1. She has never been out of the US and concerned how I can get to terminal 1 to help her navigate to get luggage and transport to our hotel. Where can we meet?

Comment: What is the question? You have plenty of time to get to terminal 1 and wait for her (like the many people who wait for arrivals). Nearly all airports have a website with maps.

Comment: Where are you arriving from (respectively), and what specific terminal are you arriving at (Terminal 2 is not really a single terminal, it is a group of 6 terminals, 3 satellites, and another terminal). Note that in many scenarios, you would only be able to meet her once she already has retrieved her luggage and gone through customs. Not sure if you could travel to CDG 1's airside without an ongoing boarding pass. And this wold apply only if you yourself didn't have any luggage.

Comment: We will be arriving from US. I WILL BE IN TERMINAL 2E and she arrives in terminal 1. We both have luggage and no other connecting flights. I'm just trying to find a common place where we can meet and share the same taxi to hotel. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can just meet here are terminal 1 arrivals following the steps [here](https://easycdg.com/travelling-terminal-1-terminal-2-cdg-airport/) to transfer between terminals:

> Arrivée terminal 2E
>   – After the automatic doors, out of the luggage delivery room, turn left, go straight on.
>   At the end of the terminal, take the escalator up.
>
> Follow the indications ″Terminal 1″ & ″CDGVAL″.
>
> [image: 1]
>
> Walk through the pedestrian walkway.
>
> [image: 2]
>
> Moving sidewalks end while entering the lobby of the TGV-RER railway station.
>
> [image: 3]
>
> Take the escalator down to the CDGVAL station.
>
> [image: 4]
>
> Get on the CDGVAL shuttle train.
>
> [image: 5]
>
> At the end of the platform, walk down the travelator.
>
> [image: 6]

Head for arrivals.

Comment: How does the OP pick up his luggage? (And can you write the steps in this answer if you keep it, as posting links is not a replacement for real instructions.)

Comment: @Willeke At the luggage hall, as said in my answer. Edited

Comment: You mean they will meet outside the secure area? (Which is what I would have suggested, but it is not clear in your answer.)

Comment: They have no choice but to meet outside the secure area. The traveling companion will have to go through immigration (assuming this is a direct flight from outside the Schengen area), baggage claim, and customs before meeting at arrivals.